# Rails: Dry content_for before yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial, yield, content-for

I have a partial that need to include some js: view/main/**_address_slider.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :scripts  do %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'swipeslider/dist/idangerous.swiper.min' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'fineuploader' %>
<% end %>
...
```

I have a testing page: view/main/**test_partial_address_slider.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :scripts  do %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'swipeslider/dist/idangerous.swiper.min' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'mycustomplugin' %>
<% end %>
<% render 'address_slider' %>
```

I have a specific test layout: view/layouts/**test.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Social Network">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title><%= @meta_title %></title>
<%= yield :meta %>
<%= yield :styles %>
<%= yield :scripts %>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<%= display_flash %>
<%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Than in my controller: controllers/main_controller

```
def test_partial_address_slider
render "test_partial_address_slider", layout: "test"
end
```

The rendered page contains the js import of swipeslider/dist/idangerous.swiper.min twice.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Social Network">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>....</title> 
<script src="/assets/swipeslider/dist/idangerous.swiper.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/swipeslider/dist/idangerous.swiper.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/fineuploader.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/mycustomplugin.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Can I remove the duplicate from the content_for before the yield in my layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper like this:

```
def yield_something_once
  unless @yielded_something
    @yielded_something = true
    content_for :something
  end
end
```

Or just use `content_for(:smth, '')` right after `yield :smth` to clear it.

Comment: not exactly because you are trying to say something like if you have already yielded :scripts, do not yield it anymore. But I want to stack all the content_for :scripts (because they may be different) and than travel the entire :script content_for and  remove the duplicate.

Comment: There is no such functionality. You must define array of scripts as instance variable and use helper(s) to add scripts. Or you can try `<% content_for :smth do %><%= yield :smth if content_for? :smth %> here is additional html<% end %>` (I haven't try it, but it seems to be ok).

Comment: Sorry, I've just read that by default `content_for` works like you want (in 4.1, haven't checked other versions). It concatenates result if called multiple times: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for

Comment: Thanks prcu for the info. I'm using an older version of rails but I plan to migrate soon.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix but it looks horrible!

```
<% s = yield(:scripts)  %>
<%= (((s.split("<script").uniq.collect{|x| x.strip}).reject(&:empty?)).map! { |word| "<script #{word}" }).join("\n").html_safe %>
```